# Asp.net 5 web api dependency resolver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject, structuremap

I have created project with an asp.net 5 web api template. The `startup.cs` file content is like this.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

I want to use a IoC framework like Autofac, StructureMap and Ninject. But How can I change default web api dependency resolver with a framework?

For example StructureMap container is set like this:

```
        var container = new StructureMap.Container(m=>m.Scan(x =>
                                                             {
              x.TheCallingAssembly(); 
              x.WithDefaultConventions();

                                                             }));
```

But can not set it in web api life.

Comment: There is currently a project in development to bring StructureMap into the wonderful world of ASP.NET Core 1.0.  See their [github project](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap.dnx). They have examples on how to get to it configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the StructureMap.Dnx project:

https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap.dnx

### Usage

The package contains a single, public extension method, `Populate`.
It's used to populate a StructureMap container using a set of `ServiceDescriptors` or an `IServiceCollection`.

#### Example

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using StructureMap;

public class Startup
{
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddWhatever();

        var container = new Container();

        // You can populate the container instance in one of two ways:

        // 1. Use StructureMap's `Configure` method and call
        //    `Populate` on the `ConfigurationExpression`.

        container.Configure(config =>
        {
            // Register stuff in container, using the StructureMap APIs...

            config.Populate(services);
        });

        // 2. Call `Populate` directly on the container instance.
        //    This will internally do a call to `Configure`.

        // Register stuff in container, using the StructureMap APIs...

        // Here we populate the container using the service collection.
        // This will register all services from the collection
        // into the container with the appropriate lifetime.
        container.Populate(services);

        // Finally, make sure we return an IServiceProvider. This makes
        // DNX use the StructureMap container to resolve its services.
        return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation here might help:

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#replacing-the-default-services-container